# how to generate multiple tables using displaytag in jsp dynamically?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, displaytag

Hey i have to generate multiple tables. User request for some thing say details of houses,so the respective data is retrieved from the database and then some calculation is performed and tables have to generated accordingly. So it depends on the request of the User for eg. if he select 3 houses then i have to display 3 different table with respective data in it and if 4 houses then 4 tables. In all a dynamic jsp.

I know there is some way using displaytags. I'm new to this technique. And also are there any good tutorials on displaytags apart from its home site to make my understanding for it more thorough?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These can help you.

[Display tag library 1.2](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/1.2/)

[Pagination Using Display Tags](http://www.javaworkspace.com/displayTags.do)

[Display Tag Examples](http://demo.displaytag.org/displaytag-examples-1.1/)